# Configure SUTime for StanfordNLP in Spanish - Java

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition, sutime

I'm having trouble setting the SUTime in the spanish version that comes with in the 
**stanford-spanish-corenlp-2018-10-05-models.jar**

In Stanford documents it says that the options `ner.applyNumericClassifiers = true` and
`ner.useSUTime = true` is only valid for the English version, but the spanish jar comes with a **spanish.sutime.txt** included and I would like for it to work.

I tried with this code:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner");

props.setProperty("tokenize.language", "es");
...         
...
props.setProperties("sutime.rules", "edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/spanish.sutime.txt");
```

I don't really know how to move on and I haven't seen this issue in any other question, maybe someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Spanish will run SUTime by defaulting 3.9.2.  You can just use these properties:

```
ner.model = edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/spanish.ancora.distsim.s512.crf.ser.gz
ner.applyNumericClassifiers = true
ner.useSUTime = true
ner.language = es
```

You can get the default Spanish properties with:

```
Properties props = LanguageInfo.getLanguageProperties("spanish");
```

Comment: For this sentence: "El verano pasado, se reunieron todos los martes por la tarde, de 1:00 p.m. a 3:00 p.m.", it yields, only one: "[41, 47]: martes --> 2020-06-02-WXX-2". Why are other expressions not identified?